# How to make goat milk safe for consumption?

Tags: food-safety, food-poisoning, milk

The milk under consideration is from a goat that is not from a goat-farm, just a loose goat that eats whatever she gets, hanging around mostly garbage (in India), if we milk her and boil the milk once, is such milk safe to consume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find directions for [pasteurizing goat milk](http://www.everything-goat-milk.com/milk-pasteurization.html)  many places online, and that should render it safe from pathogens. However, it will do nothing to protect you from heavy metals, pesticides, and other toxins that goat might be ingesting. Considering that it's eating from garbage piles, I would consider it very likely the milk contains at least some toxins. I would not drink it. If you do drink it, I would suggest not giving it to children and pregnant women.

Comment: The serial downvoting is becoming more than tiresome.

Comment: Thank you so much Carey, because of very high acidity and a patch (ulcer) in my digestive track, just below the rib-cage, my doctor advised me to drink milk, but cow and buffalo milk gives me gas, to avoid that I searched for alternative and it was goat's milk, but in India it is not available, so I had to get the goat milk from a person whose primary business is something else, he has few goats to whom he feeds vegetable-cuttings, but I also saw the goats in the garbage, that made me wonder if the milk is safe.